# Filter JSON response Java Spring - RESTful service

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm trying to hide certain fields in a GET based on whether or not a user is internal.

Here is a snippet from my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "rules", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public StandardJSON list(@ActiveUser ActiveUserId userId)
{
    StandardJSON sj = new StandardJSON();
    sj.setErrors(new ArrayList<String>());
    sj.setData(service.listAllRules());
    return sj;
}
```

The above returns the following JSON:

```
{
    "customerProfileId": "",
    "lastModifiedBy": "",
    "location": "",
    ...
}
```

I can determine if a user is internal or not using a getIsInternalUser() method.

How would I filter one of the json items if a user is external?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use [Genson - Java and Scala to JSON conversion library](http://owlike.github.io/genson/) then it can be done like this. It will exclude the "foo" field from Bar class.

```
Genson genson = new Genson.Builder().exclude("foo", Bar.class).create();
genson.serialize(yourObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

A resource should be uniform. This means that a JSON referenced by an URL should yield the exact same result regardless of "who" asks for it. The only thing I am aware of are different MediaTypes.

If you need to differentiate informations for types of users make it *visible* by modifying the URL (e.g. add an `/internal` or similar wherever it fits).
As a result you'll get a different URL/resource, where all kinds of private/internal informations could be served. To access this resource the auth should take place accordingly.

Comment: In that case, I'm still curious what the easiest way to change what JSON gets returned is, with minimal mucking inside my DTOs... is it possible within the controller to filter certain fields?